# How can I use Lambda as a verifier for my S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a web app that requires file storage for images. I am planning on using AWS S3 to store these files, but I do not know how to keep the images private for each user. I know I can use Cognito and S3 roles to do this as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_s3_cognito-bucket.html), but I want the ability for users of the same company to have a shared S3 directory. Is there a way I can use Lambda as an authorizer instead of cognito to do this? I don't want to pass files through Lambda. I simply want to use it to block access to specific bucket directories.

Comment: Company network usually behind a NAT, in that case you can use S3 bucket policy to limit access to your company IP.

Comment: How would your system know who are "users of the same company"? Would you want them to authenticate to an application, or would they have IAM logins, or (as @spqa suggested) could they be identified by their network connection to S3 somehow? If you can tell us more about how to identify these "users", then we could offer a suitable method of controlling access.

Comment: Each user has their own Cognito login. Their uuid is used to query a company uuid in a dynamoDB table. This let's me have a Lambda function that can determine the uuid of the company based on the user.